# Git merging two different of a docx files

Tags: git, file, merge, docx

Me and a couple of friends are developing a website and our work is on git. We had the starting files there and from there we have changed some of them (.pdf and .docx) to new versions. However, instead of overriding them and later tracking the changes, everyone added new files. Now we have every single version of the documents in a different file, which defeats the purpose of version control. I want to maintain the history and dates when each files is added.
Any way of doing that if they are in the same branch? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: "Any way of doing that if they are in the same branch?" what do you mean by this? If you overwrite the files you'll have the entire document history, but you can't collaborate on a pdf/docx (multiple people can't make edits and you won't be able to merge changes or see the diff). ...Generally you're better off simply using a text file and generating a pdf/docx when you need it.

Comment: In the begging I tried simply renaming the files in my local repository and hoped that the OS would write on top of the older file and I could commit and Git would preserve the history. But that did not work. I would try it through the cmd as well. Thanks

Comment: "But that did not work." what do you mean by this?

Comment: The OS (Windows) does not allow to change the name to be the same as two files and then for it to keep only the later one. The only option was name.file(2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be hard work for you. The easiest way is to remove the files all together, then start committing them one by one according to history. each time you commit use

```
git commit --date="Wed Feb 16 14:00 2011 +0100" -m "Whatever"
```

this will be somewhat tedious though.

Another option is to jump to each commit someone added a file, and open a branch there. Change the file name to the final name with `git mv`, then on the master branch merge the new branch in. This will make for a convoluted tree, but preserve history.

Comment: Which one would be a better practice? More professional?

Comment: @JoanaTrashlieva that's subjective, I prefer the second method because it doesn't mess with history, but you can discuss it with your group.